# How can we decrease saturation of UIView in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, swiftui

I have `UITableView` having list of levels of a game. I want to decrease saturation of those records which are locked for user by decreasing saturation of its `UITableViewCell`. I was going through WWDC 2019 `SwiftUI` tutorial where I saw that it is easily done in `SwiftUI` through `.saturation` property of any view and it will decrease saturation of entire view including its subviews as following:

> Normal View

[image]

> View with decreased saturation

[image]

Is there any way to achieve the same programatically in Swift? Decrease saturation of color is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

updated answer (just for saturation - stackoveflow rules: ONE question, one answer, not more questions...)

```
extension UIImage {

    func withSaturationAdjustment(byVal: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
        guard let cgImage = self.cgImage else { return self }
        guard let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorControls") else { return self }
        filter.setValue(CIImage(cgImage: cgImage), forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        filter.setValue(byVal, forKey: kCIInputSaturationKey)
        guard let result = filter.value(forKey: kCIOutputImageKey) as? CIImage else { return self }
        guard let newCgImage = CIContext(options: nil).createCGImage(result, from: result.extent) else { return self }
        return UIImage(cgImage: newCgImage, scale: UIScreen.main.scale, orientation: imageOrientation)
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        let image = UIImage(named: "b")
        view.addSubview(UIImageView(image: image))

        let imageView2 = UIImageView(image: image?.withSaturationAdjustment(byVal: 0.3))
        imageView2.frame.origin.y = 300
        view.addSubview(imageView2)

    }


}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: I am looking for decreasing saturation for entire view including its subviews..

Comment: You asked 2 questions. First: saturation with value. I have answered that. Second: entire view -> new question. So please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Yes.. my first question is covered by your answer. Answer upvoted!